# Get extensions list in Asterisk with AMI

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I'm running Asterisk 11.4.0 and I've got access to it with AMI. How can I get list of all extensions (not peers or users)?

For example, I've got dialplan like this:

```
exten = _XXXX,1,Verbose(Start recording!)
exten = _XXXX,2,NoOp()
exten = _XXXX,3,Set(SCREEN_FILE=${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%d.%m.%Y-%H:%M:%S)}_${CALLERID(num)}>${EXTEN}.gsm)
exten = _XXXX,4,MixMonitor(${SCREEN_FILE},b)
exten = _XXXX,5,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN})
exten = _XXXX,6,StopMonitor()
exten = _XXXX,7,Hangup()
exten = _49000030[0-9a-zA-Z.@_/-].,1,Goto(test1,${EXTEN},1)
exten = _49000033[0-9a-zA-Z.@_/-].,1,Goto(test2,${EXTEN},1)
```

So, my extensions are _XXXX, *49000030[0-9a-zA-Z.@*/-]. and *49000033[0-9a-zA-Z.@*/-].

Comment: Do you mean you need dialplan?

Comment: Not full dialplan. I need all extensions, mentioned in dialplan.

Comment: That will higly depend of your dialplan. But you always can issue via ami "Command" "dialplan show from-local"  or something like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hate answering my own questions, but...
For this purpose one can use AMI command like this:

```
Action: 'GetConfig',
Filename: 'extensions.conf',
Category: 'default'
```

In the response, you will get object containing each line of "default" context as it's field. All the extensions can be easily parsed from it.